# What are the "new hash functions" in cuckoo hashing?

Tags: performance, algorithm, dictionary, hash, hashtable

I am reading about cuckoo hashing from Pagh and Rodle and I can't understand the meaning of this paragraph:

> It may happen that this process loops, as shown in Fig. 1(b).
>   Therefore the number of iterations is bounded by a value “MaxLoop” to
>   be specified in Section 2.3. If this number of iterations is reached,
>   we rehash the keys in the tables using new hash functions, and try
>   once again to accommodate the nestless key. There is no need to
>   allocate new tables for the rehashing: We may simply run through the
>   tables to delete and perform the usual insertion procedure on all keys
>   found not to be at their intended position in the table.

What does it mean by **using new hash functions**?
In the insert algorithm the table is resized. Are we supposed to have a "pool" of hash functions to use somehow? How do we create this pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they're expecting new hash functions, just like they say. Fortunately, they don't require a pile of new algorithms, just slightly different hashing behavior on your current data set.

Take a look at section 2.1 of the paper, and then Appendix A. It discusses the construction of random [universal hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing).

A simple, hopefully illustrative example, is to suppose you've got some normal hash function you like, that operates on blocks of bytes. We'll call it `H(x)`. You want to use it to produce a family of new, slightly different hash functions `H_n(x)`. Well, if `H(x)` is good, and your requirements are weak, you can just define `H_n(x) = H(concat(n,x))`. You don't have nice strong guarantees about the behaviors of `H_n(x)`, but you'd expect most of them to be different.

Comment: If I understand correctly we either a) get a new hash function from this set you mention and keep the table size fixed or b) resize the table using the same 2 hash functions and never changing them?

Comment: Both options will almost certainly break the current loop. If you're not concerned about the amount of space you'll be taking up, resizing might be more useful, as it'll lower the odds of another loop (until you have more keys stored, anyways). Keep in mind that resizing is sort of a change of hash function, as well, because you're probably using the hash function modulo the size of the tables; increase the size and you'll change where things end up.

Comment: So if we use (a) i.e. a new hash keeping the table size fixed, how is the table size determined? From the paper it is not clear to me. If the number of keys to be inserted is unknown how is it possible to derive some table size for the cuckoo algorithm?

Comment: I mean if we use a new hash function and rehash this means that the table size remains the same. So how is the table size determined and when does it grow?

Comment: The simplest thing to do would just be to specify a load factor for every hash table. Let the user pick it, or use some default. When the number of items in the table reaches the table size * the load factor, you grow it. Smaller load factors should mean more performance (fewer conflicts), but also more wasted space.